# Why does my rig deform my mesh?

Tags: rigging

I have been following three or four quadraped tutorials on youtube. In pose mode whenever I move the leg and the IK on my cat it deforms and bulges really badly how can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without testing the mesh myself, my guess would be that the weight painting is off, and the bones wind up not controlling the right vertices.

Comment: I can get into weight painting mode but I can't seem to go through selecting the different bones. It just stays with a brush and paints weights for one bone

Comment: So the mesh is in weight paint mode, and the bones are in pose mode, right?  You probably need to put the bones in pose mode first, and then go to weight paint mode on the mesh.  Then you should be able to right-click on the different bones to switch to their vertex groups for painting.

Comment: Nope. I can paint weights but I can't select bones with any of my mouse buttons

Comment: ah hang on, I can select bones in the vertex groups tab

Comment: yes. One of the rear bones had the other rear bones weight painting all over it. I have cleared that and it doesn't bulge anymore but it still twists horribly when I try and animate it

Comment: It still deforms. I have added a picture of the bones in octahedral mode you can see some of them are huge and fat and others really thin. is this something to do with it? I can't seem to scale them

Comment: The armature has a scale which is not equal to one. Apply scale in edit mode to the armature : ctrl+A then scale